# "Unexpected token :" from simple API call

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I'm trying to do a very basic GET request to the [Codewars API](http://dev.codewars.com/#api-reference), but for some reason I'm getting an error saying `Unexpected token :`.

Here is my code:

```
var apiKey = 'iJUXzfpo96eUXXa-BzsT';
var baseURL = 'https://www.codewars.com/api/v1';
var user = 'GiacomoSorbi';

// Example GET user
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `${baseURL}/users/${user}?${apiKey}`,
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owy6ktnq/2/). Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a link to the [response](https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/GiacomoSorbi?iJUXzfpo96eUXXa-BzsT&callback=jQuery2130008309899596497416_1445494550614&_=1445494550615) I get.

Comment: This is a typical error if the endpoint returns JSON instead of JSONP. Can you post the response? Does the server support JSONP at all?

Comment: ^ and that's it, [**https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/GiacomoSorbi?iJUXzfpo96eUXXa-BzsT**](https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/GiacomoSorbi?iJUXzfpo96eUXXa-BzsT) returns regular JSON, not JSONP

Comment: Hey Felix, I updated my post to include the response. I'm not sure what you mean by the server supporting JSONP, I'm new to AJAX and I wanted to try making a simple API call in JSFiddle. I guess there's other stuff I'm not aware of? Yes, the link returns JSON not JSONP, but if I do `dataType: json`, it causes some other issue saying `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/GiacomoSorbi. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: The [docs](http://dev.codewars.com/) don't seem to mention JSONP at all and CORS headers are not set either. You cannot access this API directly from browser JS.

Comment: I guess the first step would then be to learn what JSONP is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP . Basically it's a response format. If the server doesn't provide the response in that format, you cannot tell jQuery to expect it.